# `console.log([])` and `console.log([].toString())` provide different outputs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've noticed that, in NodeJS, `console.log([])` and `console.log([].toString())` produce `[]` and a blank string, respectively. I'm wondering why this is so and how I can get the output of `console.log([])` as a string?

I understand for arrays, I can simply wrap the `.toString()` with brackets `[]`, but for other constructed objects, say a `Buffer`:

```
var b = new Buffer('hi');

console.log(b); // <Buffer 68 69>
console.log(b.toString()); // hi
console.log('' + b); // hi
```

Is is possible to get the bare `console.log(b)` output as a string so I can perhaps concatenate it with another string?

Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately I am trying to get `console.log`'s behavior as a string. I have edited my question to reflect my intent.

Comment: Wouldn't `b.toString` print `[Function]`?

Comment: Whoops, I meant `toString()`, I've updated my question.

Comment: consoles sniff types for colored display. some even sniff prototype methods and sneak them into the visual array representation...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you use node.js.

Read the documentation. [`console.log`](http://nodejs.org/api/console.html#console_console_log_data) uses [`util.format`](http://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_format_format).

So the answer is:

```
var util = require('util');
var b = new Buffer('hi');
var str = util.format(b);
```

Comment: You're a hero, @alexeten. I'll accept this answer when it lets me.